# How to define the 'From' field for email notification in one command from execute shell

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have Jenkins pipeline (illinXXX) with execute shell, which part of it runs the below command:

```
echo "LDAP server is down"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t arielma@gmail.com
```

Any idea how can I change the 'From' field? current I'm getting it from:

```
jenkins@illinXXXX.localdomain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how can I change the 'From' field?

Use the `-f` flag.

```
-fname

Sets the name of the ''from'' person
```

Like so:

```
echo "foo" | sendmail -f maulinglawns -t root@localhost
```

Result:

```
From maulinglawns@debian10  Wed Jan 22 21:11:24 2020
Return-Path: 
Received: from debian10 (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by debian10 (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1) with ESMTP id 00MKBOq3005526
        for ; Wed, 22 Jan 2020 21:11:24 +0100
Received: (from root@localhost)
        by debian10 (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id 00MKBO0K005511
        for root@localhost; Wed, 22 Jan 2020 21:11:24 +0100
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2020 21:11:24 +0100
From: maulinglawns@debian10
Message-Id: 

foo
```

Comment: Tnx! I tried earlier with `-t -f` first and it didn't work, so I thought the code is not right. now I realize it's just a matter of order

Answer (score 0):

In a Jenkins Pipeline, you don't need to shell out to sendmail.  You can use the [official email plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/):

```
emailext (
    subject: "A message from the Jenkins job ${env.JOB_NAME}",
    body: "LDAP Server is down",
    to: "arielma@gmail.com",
    from: "me@mydomain.com",
)
```